# Fill a table with what is selected in a select, with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to show in my page data that I get from the DB (MySQL) through Ajax. In my view I have 3 selects from which they will obtain the information for the query and a button that performs the action. However, when I press the button, it doesn't paint anything for me in the table I want to fill. But when I throw a console.log if I see the data, ordered as an array of objects. It doesn't throw me errors as such, but it doesn't show me the information in the view.

My javascript code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#searchData').click(function() {
            var url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Dashboard_admin/search_report') ?>";
            var id_compania = document.getElementById('id_compania').value;
            var id_activity = document.getElementById('id_activity').value;
            var month_ = document.getElementById('month_').value;
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'id_compania': id_compania,
                    'id_activity': id_activity,
                    'month_': month_
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        html += '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].dttime + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].amount + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].description + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].frequency + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].Month_pay + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].Year_pay + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].dttime_pay + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#datos').html(html);
                }
            });
        })
    })
```

My knowledge in ajax is quite little, so as far as I have come it has been thanks to many doubts that I have solved with questions from here.

This is the view code:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Company: </label>
                        <select id="id_compania" name="id_compania" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">-SELECT-</option>
                            <?php
                                for ($i = 0; $i < count($compania_list); $i++) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$compania_list[$i]->id_compania.'">'.$compania_list[$i]->nombrec.'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Activities: </label>
                        <select id="id_activity" name="id_activity" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">-SELECT-</option>
                            <?php
                                for ($i = 0; $i < count($activity_list); $i++) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$activity_list[$i]->id_activity.'">'.$activity_list[$i]->activities.'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Month: </label>
                        <select id="month_" name="month_" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">-SELECT-</option>
                            <option value="1">January</option>
                            <option value="2">February</option>
                            <option value="3">March</option>
                            <option value="4">April</option>
                            <option value="5">May</option>
                            <option value="6">June</option>
                            <option value="7">July</option>
                            <option value="8">August</option>
                            <option value="9">September</option>
                            <option value="10">October</option>
                            <option value="11">November</option>
                            <option value="12">December</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <center>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="searchData">Search</button>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <table class="stripe hover multiple-select-row data-table-export nowrap">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="table-plus datatable-nosort">Date</th>
                                <th class="table-plus datatable-nosort">Amount</th>
                                <th class="table-plus datatable-nosort">Description</th>
                                <th class="table-plus datatable-nosort">Frequency</th>
                                <th class="table-plus datatable-nosort">Month</th>
                                <th class="table-plus datatable-nosort">Year</th>
                                <th class="table-plus datatable-nosort">Datetime Pay</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id='datos'>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

I am attaching the function of my controller and that of my model, I am working with CodeIgniter 3 and my version of PHP in the Hosting is 7.4.25.

Controller:

This function helps me to load the view and fill the select with data

```
public function show_report() {
    if ( $this->admin->logged_id() ) {
        $data['compania_list'] = $this->admin->get_compania_list_admin(); 
        $data['activity_list'] = $this->admin->get_activity_list();
        $this->load->view("reports", $data);
    } else {
        redirect("login_admin");
    }
}//fin show_report
```

And this other function is the one that does the job of querying the model

```
public function search_report() {
    $id_compania = $this->input->post('id_compania');
    $id_activity = $this->input->post('id_activity');
    $month_ = $this->input->post('month_');
    $data['search'] = $this->admin->search_report($id_compania, $id_activity, $month_);
    echo json_encode($data);
    //$this->load->view("reports", $data);
}
```

And my model is the following:

```
function search_report($id_compania, $id_activity, $month_) {
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%m/%d/%y') AS dttime, amount, description, frequency, Month_pay, Year_pay, DATE_FORMAT(datetime_pay, '%m/%d/%y') AS dttime_pay");
    $this->db->from('payment_reports');
    $this->db->join('compania', 'compania.id_compania = payment_reports.id_compania');
    $this->db->join('activities', 'activities.id_activity = payment_reports.id_activity');
    $this->db->where('payment_reports.id_compania=',$id_compania);
    $this->db->where('activities.id_activity=', $id_activity);
    $this->db->where('MONTH(datetime)=', $month_);
    $this->db->where('YEAR(datetime) = YEAR(NOW())');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I asked this question on the Stack Overflow page in Spanish, however, no one has answered it and I have been trying to solve it for more than a month. A solution that they tried to give me was to append `JSON.parse` but it throws me the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)     at Object.success (show_report:329:24)     at i (script.js:2:28017)     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (script.js:2:28783)     at A (script.js:4:14035)     at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (script.js:4:16323)
```

Even if I added the **MIME** header in my backend where I return the **json_decode**(response of my query) but it didn't make any changes `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

I ask the question with the help of the translator because my English is very bad, but if I need to solve this and I don't know what else to do

Comment: "it doesn't show me the information in the view" - what is returned instead? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? Does the response contain the data it should contain, in the format it should be in?

Comment: in controller search_report() do a `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);die();`

Comment: @nico haase it doesn't return anything, as such the "html" variable is not filled with the information that comes from the "data". I wanted to upload some images to show you what I mean but the page wouldn't let me load them. The table stays blank, whereas when you open the console in the browser, the information is there.

Comment: @Vickel when doing that it throws me an alert with the data in an object array format and the table shows "undefined" in all the columns.

Comment: but that is good news, your Post data arrives correctly, now you have to debug your model (check with `echo '<pre>';print_r($data); die();`

Comment: It gives me the information in json format and at the same time orders it as an array of objects. Is there a way I can share you a picture of what it looks like?

Comment: "It gives me the information in json format" - in **valid** JSON format?

Comment: Hello, yes it is a valid json format, however when I add the JSON.parse it marks the error that I indicated in my question, but when I validate the information, it is a correct JSON

Answer (score 0):

change dataType in ajax like:

```
dataType: "html",
```

let me know if this solved your problem

Comment: Hi, I made the change but it didn't change anything, except that it created a kind of loop of "undefined" rows in the columns

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to move your datos id to the tbody.
Then, set your javascript like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchData').click(function() {
        var url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Dashboard_admin/search_report') ?>";
        var id_compania = document.getElementById('id_compania').value;
        var id_activity = document.getElementById('id_activity').value;
        var month_ = document.getElementById('month_').value;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'id_compania': id_compania,
                'id_activity': id_activity,
                'month_': month_
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var html = '';
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#datos').append('<tr><td>' + data[i].dttime + '</td><td>' + data[i].amount + '</td><td>' + data[i].description + + '</td><td>' + data[i].frequency + '</td><td>' + data[i].Month_pay + '</td><td>' + data[i].Year_pay + '</td><td>' + data[i].dttime_pay + '</td></tr>');
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?